# Regex match method is not works correctly

Tags: c#, regex

I have created a Regex as below, but the Match method does not work correctly:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(" + SearchText + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if(regex.Match(item).Success) { ... }
```

For example, if I set `SearchText` to `e.`, and i set `item` to `es`, then Success is true.

Similarly, if have set `SearchText` to `$` or `.`, then a match with `4` returns Success as true.

How come this is happening, and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please add some examples of what you are trying to match and what values of SearchText you are matching with.

Comment: Example,   I have a SearchText  "e."  and the Match text is "es" but its returns true.

Comment: yeah because thats how regex works... "." is any character

Comment: Check https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: If you want to match with the literal "." you use "\."

Comment: regex is not works for dot(.)??

Comment: just dot(.) matches any character

Comment: Maybe SearchText is not properly formed. look into this msdn link for usage of Regex.Match method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, if you are just interested in determining whether the text matches the pattern and don't want to actually get the match value, `IsMatch()` is a better candidate than `Match()`.

Comment: Florian Schmidinger, Thank you for your answer, how can i overcome this issue, i need to search dot(.) alone

Comment: then use \.   ...escape it

Comment: a fellow mentioned https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx before ... you can use that too to safly escape those special regex characters

Comment: i don't want to skip dot(.) i need to search the dot(.) alone

Comment: thats not skipping them ... thats replacing it with the literal "."

Answer (score 4):

The other question is if you are only looking for literals, why do you use Regex at all.

```
string item = "bla bla e. bla";
bool result = item.Contains("e."); //returns true
```

**Edit**

Case insensitive:

```
result = item.IndexOf("e.", 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
```

Comment: I need a regex for my internal purpose in my application

Comment: In that case i really recommend to grab a book... the small one of o'reilly will do just fine. stackoverflow can help you with specific problems, however its not a place for "how do i learn regex".

Comment: This is case-sensitive though. And since `Contains` doesn't have a `StringComparison` parameter you could convert everything to lower- or uppercase. Or use something like [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) which does support it.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a regex there are a bunch of common characters which have special meanings.  For example, the period (`.`) character will match any character at all so if you wanted to match the words `dog` and `dig`, you could use the regex `d.g`.

There are MANY different special characters you can use, you should see the [full .NET Regex documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

This makes matching specific things slightly more complicated when you want to match something specific, like the end of a sentence.  To match `dog.` you actually have to pass in `dog\.` as the regex to match against.  You can use the [`Regex.Escape(string str)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) method to escape most simple strings, before passing them into your Regex constructor.